# node_modules packaging fail (Webpack or Browserify)

Tags: node.js, webpack, browserify, aws-lambda, knex.js

I'm trying to bundle my node.js application with webpack or browserify, but I need some backend modules such as knex, bookshelf and others.

But webpack and browserify fail to package these modules since they do some strange stuff with require()...

I got these kind of errors :`Cannot find module 'sqlite3'` or `Error: Cannot find module './dialects/postgres/index.js'`

I can't ignore my node_modules directory since I need the modules in the package because I can't access the environment where my package will be used. (AWS Lambda)

I don't need webpack or browserify to optimize my node_modules but I need them, is there a way to tell webpack or browserify to just bundle the node_module folder and trust me if a require is missing ?

EDIT: I'm using serverless to test and deploy my lambdas and the only plugins allowing me to use ES2015 with babel force me to use webpack / browserify

Thank you :)

Comment: You can just import these modules, usually you don't need to bundle whole modules dir

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can incorporate `node_modules` in the your Lambda package (the zip file containing your code that you upload in Amazon Lambda) and don't need to package it (I mean create a file with Webpack or Browserify).

Some node modules are not meant to be used in the browser and do not support packaging because they use dynamic requires. They can have good reasons to do that, specially ORMs like Bookshelf or Sequelize.

[Webpack can manage simple dynamic requires](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html), but it works only for rules easy to parse. If you really want to use webpack for whatever reason, you could have a look to the [ContextReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#contextreplacementplugin) but I don't think it worth the effort.

Comment: I added a bit more of context to my question, and the reasons i'm using webpack / browserify

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and finally got it to work with webpack (don't know about browserify) by adding this to my webpack config:

```
{
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/\.\.\/migrate/, '../util/noop.js'),
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/\.\.\/seed/, '../util/noop.js'),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/mariasql/, /\/knex\//),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/mssql/, /\/knex\//),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/mysql/, /\/knex\//),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/mysql2/, /\/knex\//),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/oracle/, /\/knex\//),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/oracledb/, /\/knex\//),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/pg-query-stream/, /\/knex\//),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/sqlite3/, /\/knex\//),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/strong-oracle/, /\/knex\//),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/pg-native/, /\/pg\//)
  ]
}
```

If you're using serverless-webpack like me, you'll have to explicitly npm install the normal webpack module in your project and require it in your webpack config file.

This config is specifically for my setup where I use postgres without pg-native. Just ignore the modules you're not using.

The two top plugins aren't needed for webpack to build, but they get rid of a ton of annoying warnings. They're probably a little dangerous since they could match requires in other modules than knex. I couldn't find a better way without having to write my own plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to get webpack to bundle knex properly and want to share my configuration.

We could instead use `ContextReplacementPlugin` to avoid listing all drivers not needed for the project as when using `webpack.IgnorePlugin`. A side benefit is that it would avoid ignoring these packages in other modules (as mention by @Erik Frisk).

For example, I use a mysql database with `mysql2` driver and my webpack config looks like this:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/knex\/lib\/dialects/, /mysql2\/index.js/),
  ]
```

This will only bundle `node_modules/knex/lig/dialects/mysql2/index.js` excluding other dialects thus effectively ignoring the dependency in other packages like oracledb, mssql, etc.

To find more information about `ContextReplacementPlugin` have a look at [Webpack’s ContextReplacementPlugin examples](https://gist.github.com/iamakulov/59d88d00404259abb83daaf51b70cb07):